# Regex to find out sequence of numbers in a string?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to limit sequence of numbers in string. For Example Strings as below

```
abc12345def
abc 4567 fgt
45679854 khf
```

So if there are more than 5 sequential numbers I should not allow them. above example should return

```
true
true
false
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that works in my case. 
**^((?!\d{5}).)*$** 
 This is an inverse of "\d{5,}".

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex like `\d{6,}` to find blocks of more than 5 numbers, and check whether this pattern can *not* be found in the strings. Here's an example, using Python:

```
>>> strings = ['abc12345def', 'abc 4567 fgt', '45679854 khf']
>>> [re.search(r"\d{6,}", s) is None for s in strings]
[True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you. if I understand it correctly, your case returns [false,false,true]. But I am looking for the opposite.
abc12345def -- successful Match 
abc 4567 fgt - Sucess 
45679854 khf  - No match.Fail case.

Comment: @DeathBYJava No, it returns `[True, True, False]`, as shown in the example output. You can not easily "inverse" a regex, but you can see whether it produces a match, or whether it does not. That's exactly what I do when I test `re.search(...) is None`

Comment: I was looking for an inverse regex to avoid any coding. Seems like that is not easy enough. Thanks for the update. it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression [0-9]{5,} will catch anything that has more than 5 consequence numbers.

```
>>> print re.search("[0-9]{5,}", "gon1234")
None
>>> print re.search("[0-9]{5,}", "gon12345")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x024458E0>
>>>
```

Working example:

```
import re
inputText = "gon12345"
if re.search("[0-9]{5,}", inputText):
   print "More than 5 numbers!"
else:
   print "Less than 5 numbers"
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest the converse of it in regex?
Like if string has more than 5 digits it should return false/or no match.

Comment: Note that this will also match sequences of _exactly_ five numbers. If you want to match only those with _more_ than five numbers, use `[0-9]{6,}`